# CSS isn't linking with bootstrap

Tags: css

I'm trying to implement custom CSS within my web application. I am using bootstrap.

The following code is in 'boilerplate.ejs'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>GameApp</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap stylesheet. -->
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9"
            crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../app.css">
    </head>
```

However, this isn't working. I tried testing something as simple as changing image dimensions, or background color, and it's not making those changes.

Here is a screenshot of my project directory. I believe I linked the app.css correctly.

[image: Project directory]

Comment: Check your browser source to confirm that your bootstrap is properly linked.

Comment: My bootstrap is linked, the bootstrap shows. It's my custom CSS that isn't displaying.

Comment: Show your HTML and CSS files. Better yet, set up a fiddle.

Comment: Are you actually viewing boilerplate.ejs or home.ejs?

Comment: Open Developer Tools and see if your custom CSS is being overruled

Comment: The CSS doesn't appear to be showing up when I inspect the page, however, the location where app.css and how it's linked is correct. I'm also linking the app.css after the bootstrap css.